# To what extent we can trust the oral transmission of Gathas?

Tags: avestan

Recently, the historicity of Zarathushtra as sole author of the Gathas has been questioned by some philologists, who have focused on the lengthy period of oral transmission, and who consider Zarathushtra as the first to ‘make heard’ the ‘poems of praise’, but not the only one to perform them in public before they were finally written down.

Then, to what extent is it accurate compared to the original words of Zarathustra himself?
Is it possible for a linguist to detect additions after Zoroaster, which are something new inserted during the process of oral transmission?

Comment: This is a hotly debated question. This might be of interest: https://www.biblioiranica.info/orality-and-textuality-in-zoroastrianism/?fbclid=IwAR2ZeFDpC-OPxV6ihcxVVMDzOMs-i6oMnLinVuHR-yfAc6xKgaQHXI0ZOeY

Comment: @fdb What a coincidence! That debate would be what I am looking for. Thank you.